# How to get sharing PDF file's path and open that in our app?

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is a problem I couldn't solve for a long time. I want to get a PDF file's path with the share button from another application to my application which I created with xamarin. I have tried somethings and those solved my problem but that wasn't like I wanted. That was; I downloaded the pdf to my phone storage. So there was a lot of pdf on my phone. After that, I can share those pdf with my app and I can see them in there. But that wasn't exactly what I want. Let's say there is an ABC application which has a lot of pdf. I want to open those pdf and share with my Xamarin App directly without storage them. I can explain this with an example: You have a PDF which you want to share with your friends. You open that Pdf and click the Share button. After that, you'll select which application you want to use like Whatsapp, E-Mail, Skype, Discord, etc. So, at last, you can send your pdf directly to another App without store.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));



        var action = Intent.Action;
        var type = Intent.Type;

        if (Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) &&
            (type?.Equals("text/plain") ?? false))
        {
            var path = Intent.GetStringExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText);
            Console.WriteLine(path);
        }


        if (Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && (type?.Equals("application/pdf") ?? false))
        {
            var uri = (Android.Net.Uri)Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraStream);
            Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            var fullPath = GetFilePath(uri);               
            Navigate(fullPath);

        }
private string GetFilePath(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {

            string[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };
            var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, proj, null, null, null);            
            var colIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            return cursor.GetString(colIndex);            

        }
```

This is the error when I share pdf to my app:

Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: To get shares start with https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.

Comment: So what's the question now? Can't the above code receive data?

Comment: Code gets data but if there is data in phone storage.Actually i want to allowing other apps to start my activity and my app.When i share a pdf from another app to my app it gets a error something like this: 

Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: maybe you could try `MediaStore.Files`

Comment: I have tried and I got the same error again. Thanks for your help. I guess I need to try something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my code like this from this web site:

https://codemilltech.com/sending-files-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-2-android/

and it works. Hope it helps someone.

```
if (Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && (type?.Equals("application/pdf") ?? false))
                {
                    // This is just an example of the data stored in the extras 
                    var uriFromExtras = Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream) as Android.Net.Uri;
                    var subject = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject);

                    // Get the info from ClipData 
                    var pdf = Intent.ClipData.GetItemAt(0);

                    // Open a stream from the URI 
                    var pdfStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(pdf.Uri);

                    // Save it over 
                    var memOfPdf = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    pdfStream.CopyTo(memOfPdf);
                    var docsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(docsPath, "temp.pdf");

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, memOfPdf.ToArray());

                    Navigate(filePath);

                }
```